# How can I detect the HTML tag's horizontal scrolling with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm using the following JS to have the $headerDiv scroll horizontally in unison when the $rowDiv is horizontally scrolled.
I'm trying make the $rowDiv not based on a div class, but rather the HTML tag being scrolled sideways.
As a test, I switched the horizontal scrolling to the BODY tag, which works, but requires a lot of re-styling to visually work well.

```
$headerDiv = $('.header-wrapper');
$rowDiv = $('body');
$rowDiv.scroll(function(e) {
    $headerDiv.css({
        left: -$rowDiv[0].scrollLeft + 'px'
    });
});
```

If I switch it to the HTML tag, it doesn't work.

```
$headerDiv = $('.header-wrapper');
$rowDiv = $('html');
$rowDiv.scroll(function(e) {
    $headerDiv.css({
        left: -$rowDiv[0].scrollLeft + 'px'
    });
});
```

It seems as if .scroll() can detect the BODY side scrolling, but not the HTML tag. I added a console.log output in the function to fire off with each pixel scrolled, and I can see it only works with the BODY tag, and not the HTML tag. Is there a way to detect the HTML tag with .scroll() or with a different method?

Comment: That is because you scroll through the content within the `body` of the page which is inside of the `html` tag. So if you think about it, the page content starts and end within the `html` tags so no scroll is happening to the `html` tag.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but it seems like this script is mimicking the behavior of a `position: fixed;` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed) style rule on `.header-wrapper`. Is there a strong reason not to solve this problem with CSS?

Comment: The sort of makes sense except that I've turned on overflow-x for just the HTML tag: so the bottom scroll bar I see is the HTML tags scroll bar. I don't understand how I detect the the fact that I'm scrolling the HTML bar from side to side.

Comment: It's hard to give a solid answer/solution without the missing parts of the puzzle. Please update your question with the relevant `HTML` elements and the `CSS` so we can see the styles used on them. If possible a working snippet/demo would be much easier to work with.

Comment: Do not consider `<html>` a "normal" tag, because it's not. It has and needs a lot of exceptions to function. Probably the best analogy that one could make is that `<body>` is the "material" part of `<html>`. To better understand it, apply `height:0;overflow:auto;` to `<html>`. That said, the only time you should ever style `<html>` tag is when you want to pass down `height:100%` from viewport to `<body>`. That's about it. Everything else you might want on `<html>` goes on `<body>`.